# What is the principal ideal of $ T \subset X$? In a ring with operations symmetric difference and intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set, and $\mathcal P(X)$ be the power set of $X$. Consider the operations $\Delta$ = symmetric difference (a.k.a. "XOR"), and $\bigcap$ = intersection.
What is the principal ideal of $ T \subset X$?

I think it is the set of all subsets of $T$, $\mathcal P(T)$, since $T\Delta T=\emptyset$ and $( R\cap T)  \Delta T $ is $T$ without $R$, for $R \subset X$. And also, $P(X) $ is a commutative ring so $P(X) \cap T \cap P(X)=P(X) \cap T=T \cap P(X)$

Comment: And what is $R$?

Comment: @Berci sorry I edited it. I messed up the notation. R is any subset of X. I meant to write that I think the answer is the partitive set of T, not R.

Comment: Then, yes, it's the set of all subsets of $T$.